# byte array is not the same

Tags: arrays, byte

Can anyone explain me this:

```
byte [] arr = "hello".getBytes();
```

Why

```
arr.equals("hello".getBytes())
```

or

```
arr==("hello".getBytes())
```

return false?

Comment: `==` and `equals` compare references, not the contents. In general, equals for mutable objects do not consider the contents.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thks 4 the explnation.. can u pls share the link for all immutable objects in java

Comment: Unfortunately there is no comprehensive list.  The simplest I have found is classes which implement Comparable.  However there are some mutable classes in that list. (Anything ending in `Buffer`) :| http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 2):

Hope this one helps: 
http://www.java-examples.com/compare-two-java-byte-arrays-example

I think that the equals method on the byte array object only checks for the same reference and not for actual content.